# Making the web page fixed and un-zoomable

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I need to make my web page un-zoomable such that the divs don't collide each other or overlap each other. The stackoverflow site is a great example. In a case where the user zooms in the web page, the divs should be in their original positions.

[image]

**When Zoomed, it's still fixed.**

[image: When Zoomed]

What changes do I need to make to the CSS files?

Comment: You should give a fix width to your outer container

Comment: @AshishBhagat You should give example in answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050841/disable-zooming-of-the-page-in-desktop-web-browsers-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001256/how-do-you-prevent-firefox-from-zooming-in-when-pressing-ctrl-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be giving width in px. You should do it in percentage if you want your layout to stay right when you zoom in or zoom out

Comment: I am giving the width in px right now. Percentages should do the trick if I change both the height and width of all the divs?

Comment: try doing that, I think this is what u are looking for

Answer (score 1):

On your containing elements, declare an specific width.

If you look at Stack Overflows following css, you can see that they set a width on their content block.

```
#content {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

The child elements within #content also have absolute widths set

```
#mainbar {
    width: 728px;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 220px;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'/>
```

this should work